# Is it compulsory to enable Enable ICU formats for en_CA locale

Tags: locale, release-update

I have completed steps for Enable ICU Formats but now salesforce is saying in new release update that
[image]
In my org we are not using en_CA locale - still we need to enable the option.

I am really confused now. If it is mandatory:

1. How to find impacted areas/components?
2. How to test?
3. Why it is mandatory for all?

And if it is mandatory then...

I want to enable en_CA locale in my salesforce org before enforcement date, but I don't have any user using this locale and as per the docs I need to update apex classes, triggers, vf pages to API version 45 or greater.

Now the problem is: I have around 1400+ apex classes running on lower API version. Do I need to update all these in all environments?

How can I know impacted classes?

What does this en_CA really mean?

I have enabled the update when it was initially introduced, but as I don't have any user from en_CA...?!

Comment: The screenshot is taken from [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.icu_migration_enable.htm&type=5). Just to clarify this bit: en_CA seems to be what Salesforce recommends as a basis for testing on a Sandbox. (My comment is not meant to answer all your questions.)